# methods for servo or stepper synchronized multi-axis control

Tags: stepper-motor, servo, robotics, synchronization

I have designed a 6 axis robot. The main requirement of the robot is that all axes must be highly synchronized in order to create precise (sub-millimeter, sub-degree) 6DOF (x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll) trajectories in space. I implemented this robot using:

Hardware:  NI PCI-7358 controller, NI MID-7604 amplifiers, steppers

Software: NI Labview

However, I would like to move away from NI products to something more compact so that I don't have to lug around a computer cart. One example I found on [github](https://github.com/Chris-Annin/Annin-Robot-Project) is a robot where the creator used the following:

Hardware: Arduino, A4988 stepper drives, steppers

Software: python

However, with such a setup I am worried that synchronized multi-axis control will not be maintained due to Arduino processing lag. Can anyone recommend if the Arduino solution is suitable or present alternative solutions (please list your specific hardware and software)?

Comment: If you want to see what an Arduino can do in terms of multi-axis coordination, look at open source 3d printer firmwares.  But if starting from scratch, you'll have far more resources to work with on various ARM parts.  Be careful to separate "lag" from processor speed and software architecture from that of *communication* interfaces - if you already know what you want to do, get the instructions drip feeding to the executive processor a bit ahead of need.  But if you have something deciding what to do in real time, you'll need to put more care into the time taken to decide and command.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be the solution I want. 7 axis stepper controller using a raspberry pi. https://roboteurs.com/collections/all/products/slushengine-model-d

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is can someone recommend some good hardware/methods to
>   accomplish this?

Yeah, take all of your blocks in labview and find or write pieces of code that replicate the functions of the blocks. [You can even write C code in labview and make custom block](http://www.ni.com/example/3933/en/)s, so you could test each block one at a time and replace them with your own.

Or there is a [C code generator for labview](http://www.ni.com/download/-2012/3143/en/) (which I've never used and probably costs more money and probably doesn't do a great job at converting).

I would use C, because its not interpreted and would probably run better real time. If you feel the need to use python, I'd write the C first and then convert it over.

Comment: However, I would still be stuck using NI hardware (PCI-7358) which I think locks me into using Labview and all the NI drivers and windows. Please see my update to the question.

Comment: I don't answer moving target questions

Answer (score -1):

You would need an OS with real time capability. The open source CNC site is LinuxCNC for building the CNC machine. The forked project is Machinekit, which is intended to build custom machine, not related to standard G-code interpreter.

If you have enough resources, then drives and IO based on Ethercat communication protocol would be the best. It offers synchronism such that all devices take a snapshot of actual values at the same time, also the setpoint values are output at same time. Further the jitter of the OS interrupt has no relevance until the new values are computed within each communication cycle, so Linux preemption OS does the trick.

Comment: Please note that it is not a CNC project but a robot. Would this be possible with a compact Linux computer like a raspberry pi? Can you recommend a 6 axis motion controller?

Comment: What's a motion controller from your point of view?

Comment: http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/model.pci-7358.html